# Object doesn't support property or method 'for'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, next.js

I am using Next JS with one of my projects and am running into an error in Internet Explorer 11:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'for'

The error seems to origininate from the `commons` or `webpack` file, see the stack below with site blanked out:

[image]

After having a look in the files for what could be using the `.for` method it appears that it's for a few of the Symbols that are used in the bundled code.

I have tried importing `core-js` polyfils in my webpack config like so:

```
import 'core-js/features/symbol';
```

but this then throws the follow error:

> Error was not caught TypeError: Object expected

I tried another method - including a polyfil in my apps `<head>`:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.23.0/polyfill.min.js' />
```

and received the following error when I tried to run it in ie again:

> Error was not caught SecurityError

Both method I tried above (using core-js import and including the babel-polyfil library) do seem to provide a `Symbol.for` method to the dom. IE if I type `Symbol.for` before adding either polyfil I get undefined and after it returns me a function, so i'm not too sure why it's still failing.

Finally if it's of any help, here is my next config but I don't think it's anything here that's causing it:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack')
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');

module.exports =
    withFonts(withSass({
        webpack: (config, {
            dev
        }) => {

            // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
            config.node = {
                fs: 'empty'
            }
            config.plugins.push(new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(process.env))

            if (dev) {
                config.devtool = 'cheap-module-source-map';
            }

            config.module.rules.push({
                test: /\.(png|svg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 100000,
                        publicPath: './',
                        outputPath: 'static/',
                        name: '[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            })

            const originalEntry = config.entry
            config.entry = async () => {
                const entries = await originalEntry()

                if (
                    entries['main.js'] &&
                    !entries['main.js'].includes('./client/polyfills.js')
                ) {
                    entries['main.js'].unshift('./client/polyfills.js')
                }

                return entries
            }

            return config

        }
    }))
```

Comment: I create a next.js app and use `Symbol.for` in my code and it runs well in IE11 without any error. Could you please provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can have a test on our sides? Besides, I find [an example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-polyfills) of how to add polyfills, you could refer to it. And the latest version of next.js is 9, you should try to use the latest version of next.js.

Comment: yep - this is the example that I followed...

Comment: Could you please provide a simple sample or steps to reproduce? Because the issue couldn't be reproduced with only the above information. I appreciate your understanding.